# How do I prevent double confirmation in chrome with 'onbeforeunload' events in react

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, events, onbeforeunload

I want to prompt people to confirm before they leave a page.

I added and event listener in componentDidMount:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnload)
}
```

Then I wrote the event I want to happen:

```
onUnload(e) {
    var message = "Random message to trigger the browser's native alert."
    e.returnValue = message
    return message
  }
```

Then I bound the event in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onUnload = this.onUnload.bind(this)
  }
```

And finally I removed the event listener on unmount:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnload)
  }
```

Everything seems to work fine. I get the following prompt when I try and close the tab in chrome:
[image]

The problme is that I also get a reload prompt after I choose either option:
[image]

How do I get rid of the second prompt? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you put the `removeEventListener` in `onUnload`? `componentWillUnmount` might not be getting called in your case.

Comment: @DonovanM I just gave it a shot and no luck. Same behaviour as before. I assume you meant... `onUnload(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var message = "Random message to trigger the browser's native alert.";
    e.returnValue = message;
    return message;
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnload);
  }`  I did throw a console log into unmount to test your point and it seems to be firing. Thank you though. I appreciate it.

Comment: `window.removeEventListener` should be before `return message`. Anything after a return statement won't be executed. But since you said unmount is firing correctly this probably won't help much, unfortunately :(

Comment: @DonovanM No! It worked! It makes no sense to me. And that was a silly mistake on my part, but you solved my problem. You are amazing. Thank you. Would you like to offically answer the question so that I can mark your answer correct? `onUnload(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnload);
    e.preventDefault();
    var message = "Random message to trigger the browser's native alert.";
    e.returnValue = message;
    return message;
  }`

Comment: Sure, I'll do that. Thanks for offering to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `window.removeEventListener` to the `onUnmount` method to ensure it gets called. So something like this should work:

```
onUnload(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnload)

    var message = "Random message to trigger the browser's native alert."
    e.returnValue = message
    return message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a e.preventDefault() in onUnload

Comment: Unfortunatley not. Same problem. Thanks though.

  `onUnload(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var message = "Random message to trigger the browser's native alert.";
    e.returnValue = message;
    return message;
  }`